# How can you update a table with an ascending order position based on different groups in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, while-loop

I am struggling with this complex query. I am trying to insert the order position of some products. 
For example, 
I have currently table 1 with a position of NULL, I want to group each Product ID and assign each size a menu position based on ProductID group and using this FIND_IN_SET:

`FIND_IN_SET(size,"UNI,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,3XL,4XL,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60") asc;`

In other words, I want it to look like Table2.

Table1

```
ID   |   ProductID   |   Size   |   Menu_position
1    |      100      |    S     |   NULL
2    |      100      |    M     |   NULL
3    |      100      |    L     |   NULL
4    |      101      |    40    |   NULL
5    |      101      |    41    |   NULL
6    |      101      |    42    |   NULL
7    |      102      |    XS    |   NULL
8    |      102      |    L     |   NULL
```

Table2

```
ID   |   ProductID   |   Size   |   Menu_position
1    |      100      |    S     |   1
2    |      100      |    M     |   2
3    |      100      |    L     |   3
4    |      101      |    40    |   1
5    |      101      |    41    |   2
6    |      101      |    42    |   3
7    |      102      |    XS    |   1
8    |      102      |    L     |   2
```

What I collected so far:

**Number of products Group:**`select count(distinct ProductID) from Table1`

**Sort size based on specific order:** `SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(size,"UNI,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,3XL,4XL,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60") asc;`

Comment: what's the logic behind assigning such menu position?

Comment: Do the menu positions for a Product ID have to be ascending?  For example, if a product had only sizes "S" and "L", should the menu positions be 1 and 2, or are positions of 1 and 3 OK?

Comment: You can put your sizes and menu position values (integers) into a table and join to that table to get the menu position for each size.

Comment: @rd_nielsen Yes menu has to be chronological order 1 and 2, it cannot skip. This is why I just can't hard assign each value.

Comment: @vivek_23 It is for a dropdown menu

Comment: @Beck So why did you reassign 1 to `XS`? Why not continue from `4`?

Comment: @vivek_23 Because each group is different, its a variable position because not all product contains the same size combination. If it skips a number then it will throw off the position in the menu.

Comment: @Beck Can you mention those `groups`? Does `XS,L` come under `1` group? Edit your post to mention groups from `UNI,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,3XL,4XL,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60`

Comment: What are the conditions within the order? And does the query needs to be dynamic meaning no hardcored values so the same query is usable when groups are added?

Comment: @RaymondNijland The  Menu_position must have a chronological order based on the on this list: UNI,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,3XL,4XL,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60
Which ever comes first gets the value of 1, then next one is 2 , ect ect

Yes query must be reusable for each group of products.

Comment: Gordan's answer seams like it does that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables in pre-MySQL 8.0:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (@rn := if(@p = productid, @rn + 1,
                  if(@p := productid, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as menu_position
FROM (SELECT t1.*
      FROM Table1 t1
      ORDER BY ProductId,
               FIND_IN_SET(size, 'UNI,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,3XL,4XL,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60') asc
     ) AS alias CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @p := -1, @rn := 0) params;
```

In MySQL 8+, this is much simpler:

```
select t1.*,
       row_number() over (partition by productid order by FIND_IN_SET(size, 'UNI,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,3XL,4XL,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60')) as menu_position
from table1 t1
```

Comment: You guys are beasts! Thank you so much, hope to get at your level someday!

Comment: Is there a way I can add this as a view? I keep getting 
Error 1351: View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter SQL Statement:  CREATE       OR REPLACE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED

Comment: @Beck . . . There is not an easy way to add this to a view.  It is possible, but not really worth the effort, because the view would have to use a correlated subquery and would be expensive.

Comment: Thank you, I manage to put it into a store produce and made a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a two-column table containing all the the `Size` values in one column and the integer order of those sizes in the second column--call that table `menu_pos`.  Join this to your `Table` on size, to produce a table or view (call this `product_pos`) containing columns `product_id`, `size`, and `menu_pos`.  Then modify the `menu_pos` values to ensure that they are strictly sequential using a window function, such as:

```
select
    product_id,
    size,
    rank() over (partition by product_id order by menu_pos) as new_menu_pos
from
    product_pos;
```

Window functions require MySQL 8.

Comment: This wouldn't work. We can't create a new table since we can't fix a menu position. It might be `1` for a particular data set, `2` for another etc.

Comment: The accessory table only needs the integers to be in ascending order, not sequential.  The window function will ensure that the numbers are sequential.

Comment: @rd_nielsen Please tag. What do you mean by `the integer order of those sizes in the second column` ? If the window function ensures it's sequential order, why create a separate table in the DB? I think we could have the same table with a different name self joined with managing integer order of those sizes as their id itself(since it would be in ascending order anyway).

Comment: @vivek_23  "By integer order of those sizes," I mean that if "S" is to sort before "M", then the integers assigned to "S" and "M" should reflect that order--that is, the integer for "S" is smaller than the integer for "M".  If you create a separate table for this information, then your data are all in the database, not partly in the database and partly in your interface code.

Comment: @rd_nielsen I get what you are saying but this confuses me a bit now. Actually, OP has still kept things unclear. If `L` comes before `40`, why does `40` get reassigned to `1`?

Comment: @vivek_23  Because "L" and "40" are for different product IDs.  With an accessory table, `Table1` doesn't need the `Menu_position` column at all.  The accessory table of size labels and menu position ordering integers would have very few rows, but accomplish the same purpose.

Comment: `Because "L" and "40" are for different product IDs` Thanks. I wonder how I overlooked that. I need some coffee :)